# Getting unknown characters while reading excel usign java with apacahe poi

Tags: java, excel, selenium, apache-poi

I am using a framework which was developed using java and selenium. While reading values from excel using apache poi, in place of spaces, its taking unknown characters. has anyone faced this issue?. if, please let me know the solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you using the correct encoding format?? i don't see any other reason why this would happen

Comment: hi abhishek, i am using UTF-8 encoding format.

Answer (score 2):

I remember I had this problem once. If you are indeed using UTF-8 encoding, it might be a problem of your IDE (if you're using one). I fixed it by updating the encoding of my IDE.

Maybe you're facing the same problem?

Comment: Thanks @lazary . But that's not the issue with my case.